# peewee PooledMySQLDatabase has cache or buffer?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

i create a mysql connection pool like this:

```
database = PooledMySQLDatabase('test', max_connections=10,
                       **{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 3306,
                          'user': 'root', 'password': ''})


class BaseModel(Model):
class Meta:
    database = database



class Tb1(BaseModel):
    point_id = PrimaryKeyField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tb1'
```

however, where i insert a record or delete a record in database manully, in my program, select result is not change.

```
while True:
    database.connect()
    tb_list = Tb1.select()
    print(len(tb_list))
    database.close()
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
```

when i repalce PooledMySQLDatabase to MySQLDatabase the result is normal.
In my project, I want to use multithread, so I need to create a mysql pool.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

No cache, no buffer. It has to do with transaction management. Just be sure that you're running your statements in transactions and you should be fine.

Multi-threaded apps DO NOT REQUIRE A POOL with peewee. Peewee correctly manages per-thread connections even without a pool.

Comment: Multi-threaded apps , do i need run query statements in transactions

Comment: You should always use transactions.